# Use unsigned char* as istream

Tags: c++, mysql

First all sorry if I made something wrong with the question. I've been looking for two days how to do this and i cant find anything. And sorry again if this is a fool question, but Im starting with C++

I am working on a personal project and I want to use a fingerprint reader, it gives me a

```
BYTE *imageBuffer1
```

with this, I can make a file with the fingerprint info like this

```
fwrite (minutiaeBuffer1 , sizeof (BYTE) , templateSize , fp);
```

But I want to store that info into mysql with mysqlcppconn but I cant figure out how to use/cast/convert the BYTE* into an std::istream.
When I try to do something like

```
prepared_statemet->setBlob(1, minutiaeBuffer1);
```

The compiler sends me an error that says:

```
main.cpp:229:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘sql::PreparedStatement::setBlob(int, BYTE*&)’
main.cpp:229:39: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/cppconn/prepared_statement.h:63:15: note: virtual void sql::PreparedStatement::setBlob(unsigned int, std::istream*)
/usr/include/cppconn/prepared_statement.h:63:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘BYTE* {aka unsigned char*}’ to ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: There is the (deprecated) [`std::istrstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/istrstream) for this purpose.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418693/using-a-character-array-as-a-string-stream-buffer/26418951#26418951)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::stringstream should do what you want....

```
#include <sstream>

BYTE *imageBuffer1; 
// where N is the desired number if bytes
std::stringstream minutiaeBuffer1( 
          std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(imageBuffer1),N)); 

prepared_statemet->setBlob(1, &minutiaeBuffer1);
```

EDIT: Restricted length of input buffer to N

Comment: Note that this (a) will read up to the first `'\0'` character, which may not be desired since it looks like this is binary data, and (b) it will copy the buffer into an `std::string` object, which may also not be desired.

Comment: @cdhowie `std::string::assign()` indirection should solve _(a)_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Or just construct the string specifying the length. `assign()` would be an unnecessary extra step. Either way, this still requires copying the buffer.

Comment: @cdhowiem  πάντα ῥεῖ Agreed and modified code to restrict stringstream to N

Comment: If one wants to prevent copying (s|)he may implement h(is|er) owns std::streambuf. But I guess that's beyond these samples.

Comment: Thank you very much to everybody. It was solved as Oncaphillis says