# How to get part of a std::string into a streambuf without copying?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, stdstring, streambuf

I'm using boost asio a lot lately and I find that I'm working with `std::string`s and `asio::streambuf`s quite a bit. I find that I'm trying to get data back and forth between `streambuf`s and `string`s a lot as part of parsing network data. In general, I don't want to mess around with 'formatted io', so `iostream`s aren't very useful. I've found that while `ostream::operator<<()`, in spite of the official documentation, seems to relay my `string`s into `streambuf`s unmolested, `istream::operator>>()` mangles the contents of my `streambuf`s (as you would expect given that it's 'formatted').

It really seems to me like the standard library is missing a whole lot of iterators and stream objects for dealing with `streambuf`s and `string`s and unformatted io. For example, if I want to get a substring of a `string` into a `streambuf`, how do I do that without creating a copy of the `string`? A basic all-in-all-out transfer can be accomplished like:

```
// Get a whole string into a streambuf, and then get the whole streambuf back
//  into another string
{
    boost::asio::streambuf sbuf;
    iostream os(&sbuf);
    string message("abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz");
    cout << "message=" << message << endl;
    os << message;
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> sbit(&sbuf);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;
    std::string sbuf_it_wholestr(sbit, end);
    cout << "sbuf_it_wholestr=" << sbuf_it_wholestr << endl;    
}
```

prints:

```
message=abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz
sbuf_it_wholestr=abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz
```

If I want to get just part of a `streambuf` into a string, that seems really hard, because `istreambuf_iterator` isn't a random access iterator and doesn't support arithmetic:

```
// Get a whole string into a streambuf, and then get part of the streambuf back
//  into another string. We can't do this because istreambuf_iterator isn't a
//  random access iterator!
{
    boost::asio::streambuf sbuf;
    iostream os(&sbuf);
    string message("abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz");
    cout << "message=" << message << endl;
    os << message;
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> sbit(&sbuf);
    // This doesn't work
    //std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end = sbit + 7; // Not random access!
    //std::string sbuf_it_partstr(sbit, end);
    //cout << "sbuf_it_partstr=" << sbuf_it_partstr << endl;    
}
```

And there doesn't seem to be any way of directly using `string::iterator`s to dump part of a `string` into a `streambuf`:

```
// istreambuf_iterator doesn't work in std::copy either
{
    boost::asio::streambuf sbuf;
    iostream os(&sbuf);
    string message("abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz");
    cout << "message=" << message << endl;
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> sbit(&sbuf);
    //std::copy(message.begin(), message.begin()+7, sbit); // Doesn't work here
}
```

I can always pull partial `string`s out of a `streambuf` if I don't mind formatted io, but I do - formatted io is almost never what I want:

```
// Get a whole string into a streambuf, and then pull it out using an ostream
// using formatted output
{
    boost::asio::streambuf sbuf;
    iostream os(&sbuf);
    string message("abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz");
    cout << "message=" << message << endl;
    string part1, part2;
    os << message;
    os >> part1;
    os >> part2;
    cout << "part1=" << part1 << endl;    
    cout << "part2=" << part2 << endl;    
}
```

prints:

```
message=abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz
part1=abcdefghijk
part2=lmnopqrs
```

If I'm ok with an ugly copy, I can generate a substring, of course - `std::string::iterator` *is* random access...

```
// Get a partial string into a streambuf, and then pull it out using an
//  istreambuf_iterator
{
    boost::asio::streambuf sbuf;
    iostream os(&sbuf);
    string message("abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz");
    cout << "message=" << message << endl;
    string part_message(message.begin(), message.begin()+7);
    os << part_message;
    cout << "part_message=" << part_message << endl;
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> sbit(&sbuf);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;
    std::string sbuf_it_wholestr(sbit, end);
    cout << "sbuf_it_wholestr=" << sbuf_it_wholestr << endl;    
}
```

prints:

```
message=abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz
part_message=abcdefg
sbuf_it_wholestr=abcdefg
```

The stdlib also has the curiously stand-alone `std::getline()`, which lets you pull individual lines out of an `ostream`:

```
// If getting lines at a time was what I wanted, that can be accomplished too...          
{    
    boost::asio::streambuf sbuf;
    iostream os(&sbuf);
    string message("abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz\n1234 5678\n");
    cout << "message=" << message << endl;
    os << message;
    string line1, line2;
    std::getline(os, line1);
    std::getline(os, line2);
    cout << "line1=" << line1 << endl;
    cout << "line2=" << line2 << endl;
}
```

prints:
    message=abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz
    1234 5678

```
line1=abcdefghijk lmnopqrs tuvwxyz
line2=1234 5678
```

I feel like there's some Rosetta Stone that I've missed and that dealing with `std::string` and `asio::streambuf` would be so much easier if I discovered it. Should a just abandon the `std::streambuf` interface and make use of `asio::mutable_buffer`, which I can get out of `asio::streambuf::prepare()`?

Comment: What a long story. I don't think stringstreams are move enabled. I think I've seen a proposal to add that. Meanwhile, string streams are not terribly complicated so you could write it yourself

Comment: I've given a few hints in my answer, but really in the future try to target a specific question (after searching SO for existing answers, of course). This answer is so divergent as it is, I think an answer with "quick pointers" is  about all we can do.

Comment: [Related.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418693/using-a-character-array-as-a-string-stream-buffer/26418951#26418951)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > istream::operator>>() mangles the contents of my streambufs (as you would expect given that it's 'formatted').

   Open your input stream with `std::ios::binary` flag and  manipulate it with `is >> std::noskipws`
2. > For example, if I want to get a substring of a string into a streambuf, how do I do that without creating a copy of the string? A basic all-in-all-out transfer can be accomplished like

   Try like

   ```
    outstream.write(s.begin()+start, length);
   ```

   Or use `boost::string_ref`:

   ```
    outstream << boost::string_ref(s).instr(start, length);
   ```

   ---
3. > And there doesn't seem to be any way of directly using string::iterators to dump part of a string into a streambuf:

   ```
    std::copy(it1, it2, ostreambuf_iterator<char>(os));
   ```
4. Re. parsing the message lines:

   You can split into iterator ranges with `iter_split`.

   You can parse an embedded grammar on the fly with `boost::spirit::istream_iterator`

Comment: 1. Are you talking about ifstream? How do you open a generic istream with ios::binary? Also, std::noskipws doesn't help here - it just tells istream to not skip _leading_ whitespace. istream will still tokenize the input according to whitespace.

Comment: @TedMiddleton `istream_iterator<char>`, e.g. will return all chars, whitespace included with `noskipws`. I was talking about any concrete `istream&` instance, yes

Comment: I'm clearly missing something here. How do you open a generic istream with ios::binary? Can you post actual code? istream doesn't have a ctor that supports this, and I can't find any of its accessors that can annoint an istream as 'ios::binary'.

Comment: Hence I was talking about concrete `istream&` instances, not `istream` instances. I also confirmed "yes", to answer the question "Are you talking about ifstream" (although the scope is wider than files). I've tried to remove the confusion from my answer wording.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. The istream(&sbuf) that I create is a 'concrete instance', but it'll still format output, and std::noskipws still doesn't work. What are you talking about when you say 'concrete istream &'? An lvalue? Can you be more precise?

Comment: 2. This almost works - outstream.write(s.data()+start, length); is the correct form because ostream::ostream() doesn't take iterators. Which I think is a very bizarre omission from the std lib because it's so much less safe.

Comment: 3. Oops - mea cupla. Thanks - I'll try using an ostreambuf_iterator for an ostream rather than an istreambuf_iterator for an ostream (which is pretty silly of me).

Comment: No I don't think I can be more precise :( _Q. Are you talking about ifstream?_ **A. Yes**. And other streams, like string streams. In fact, `istream is(new somestreambuf("some_device_name", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary));`  should work too, but I didn't mean that :/

Comment: The only streambuf that's going to have ios::binary is going to be filestreambuf, though. I'll take your word for it that an fstream with ios:: binary + noskipws works, but a generic istream with a generic implementor of streambuf doesn't. And unfortunately I'm more interested in asio::streambuf's being handled by asio::ssl:: stream's.

Comment: I think everyone was absolutely right - my question was just much too broad and indistinct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65859/discussion-between-sehe-and-ted-middleton).

Comment: std::copy(it1, it2, ostreambuf_iterator<char>(os)); is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you just need [`std::streambuf::sputn()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sputn)

```
my_buf.sputn(mystr.data(), mystr.size());
```