# Buffer-based stringstream without copying

Tags: c++, performance, istream, istringstream

Suppose I have two APIs that I need to interact with:

- API 1 is a producer which provides me with a raw character buffer (`const char*`) and a length (say `std::size_t`).
- API 2 is a consumer which expects an `std::istream`.

I'd like to use this buffer for a `std::istringstream`, but if I'm not mistaken, I'll have to turn the raw character buffer into a `std::string` first, copying its contents. I'd like to avoid that.

So my question is: Is there a way I could directly make an `istringstream` read from a buffer without copying the buffer using the stdlib, and without writing my own `bufferstream` class?

Is there a good reason for `istringstream`s being restricted to, well, strings - especially since [using strings as buffers is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422913/)?

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418693/using-a-character-array-as-a-string-stream-buffer

Comment: @NathanOliver that's almost what I want, but I would not want to rely on implementation-defined behavior, if possible.

Comment: Write a input stream compatible wrapper around `std::string_view`?

Comment: @Luatic: Then make your own `std::streambuf` class. It's not super complicated.

Comment: `std::istringstream` only works with `std::string`, hence its name.  You need a custom `std::streambuf` to work with a raw memory buffer. There are plenty of 3rd party implementations floating around if you don't want to write your own.

Comment: @MooingDuck I had overestimated the complexity of that, but looking at the answers of the questions this is a duplicate of I see it's much easier than expected. Thanks.